# How to resolve typescript error while exporting map component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps-react

I'm facing typescript error while exporting map component with GoogleApiWrapper. It is working fine I'm not wrapping it in GoogleApiWrapper, I tried multiple solutions but no one is working for me. Anyone please look over the code and provide any suggestion. with this issue I'm getting props issues when I'm calling this component with needful props.

The issue might be related to wrapping my component inside GoogleApiWrapper.

```
import { GoogleApiWrapper,Map, Marker } from "google-maps-react";
import React from "react";
import "./GoogleMap.css";
import Autocomplete from 'react-google-autocomplete';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
export interface GoogleMapProps {
    google?: any | undefined,
    position: any,
    mapStyles?:any,
    mapColor?:any,
    handleSelect:(place: any)=>void,
    onAddressChange: (address: any) => void;
    countryID:string,
}
const GoogleMap: React.FC<GoogleMapProps> = (props:GoogleMapProps ) => {
    const {position,mapStyles,mapColor,handleSelect,countryID}=props;
    const renderMap = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '270px' }}>
                    {
                        <Map
                            google={props.google}
                            initialCenter={position}
                            center={position}
                            zoomControl={false}
                            mapTypeControl={false}
                            style={mapStyles}
                            scaleControl={false}
                            streetViewControl={false}
                            fullscreenControl={false}
                            containerStyle={{
                                position: 'absolute',
                                width: '95%',
                                height: '40%',
                                borderRadius: '12px',
                            }}
                            onReady={(mapProps, map) => {
                                console.log("Map is ready")
                            }}
                            styles={mapColor}
                        >
                            <Marker
                                position={position}
                            />
                        </Map>
                    }
                </div>
                <Autocomplete
                    className={"autocomplete_input"}
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    placeholder={"Type your address"}
                    onPlaceSelected={(place: any) => {
                        handleSelect(place)
                    }}
                    types={['(regions)']}
                    componentRestrictions={{ country: countryID }}
                />
                <svg className="svg_icon" width="23" height="25" viewBox="0 0 23 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M22.5789 20.7516L18.3102 16.0781C18.1175 15.8672 17.8563 15.75 17.5823 15.75H16.8844C18.0661 14.0953 18.7683 12.0141 18.7683 9.75C18.7683 4.36406 14.7822 0 9.86273 0C4.94326 0 0.957153 4.36406 0.957153 9.75C0.957153 15.1359 4.94326 19.5 9.86273 19.5C11.9307 19.5 13.8317 18.7313 15.3431 17.4375V18.2016C15.3431 18.5016 15.4501 18.7875 15.6428 18.9984L19.9115 23.6719C20.3139 24.1125 20.9647 24.1125 21.3629 23.6719L22.5746 22.3453C22.9771 21.9047 22.9771 21.1922 22.5789 20.7516ZM9.86273 15.75C6.83569 15.75 4.38238 13.0688 4.38238 9.75C4.38238 6.43594 6.83141 3.75 9.86273 3.75C12.8898 3.75 15.3431 6.43125 15.3431 9.75C15.3431 13.0641 12.8941 15.75 9.86273 15.75Z" fill="#96A7AF" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {renderMap()}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper(
    () => ({
      apiKey: "....key here...."
    }
  ))(GoogleMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of materials on google on React Higher-Order-Components, [like this for example](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb)

Here's my suggestion, try if this works (at least TS compiler is not complaining about anything):

```
// make 'google' not optional to satisfy props for wrapper 
export interface GoogleMapProps {
    google: any,
    position: any,
    mapStyles?:any,
    mapColor?:any,
    handleSelect:(place: any)=>void,
    onAddressChange: (address: any) => void;
    countryID:string,
}
```

...

```
// compose components like this:
export default GoogleApiWrapper(({apiKey: "....key here...."}))<GoogleMapProps>((props) => (<GoogleMap {...props} />));
```